# IText 7 - Adding border for the page

Tags: itext7

I am looking for adding page border without hardcoding width and height in IText 7.

Tried with Rectangle, but no setBorder method in Itext 7. Also, this is for the entire page.

```
        Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(100, 100);
        rect.setBorder(2);
        rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        document.add(rect);
```

**Pdf creation**

```
final PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfFileName)); 
 final Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc); 
 PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(1); 
 Rectangle pageRect = new Rectangle(page.getTrimBox());
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following piece of code allows you to draw red border around the specified page of your document. No hard-coding except page number.

```
PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(1);
Rectangle pageRect = new Rectangle(page.getTrimBox());
new PdfCanvas(page).setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.RED).setLineWidth(5).rectangle(pageRect).stroke();
```

Comment: Getting error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested page number 1 is out of bounds.
final PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfFileName));
  final Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
  
  
  PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(1);
  Rectangle pageRect = new Rectangle(page.getTrimBox());

Comment: @user1578872 Please attach your minimal code including PDF creation to the question

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: As Alexey said *"the specified page of your document"*. Your document is completely new and has no pages yet, so you cannot specify a page. First call `pdfDoc.addNewPage()` explicitly or add something to `doc` to implicitly generate a page.

Comment: Here, the border is on the corner. But, I want borderline little bit inside. Setting width and height works for top and right side but not for all the sides.