# Adding gray line b/w paragraph in iText 7

Tags: itext7

I am not sure how to add the gray line like in the image b/w paragraphs in Itext 7.

Should I use rectangle for this with very small width and the whole page length?

```
Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(1, 400);
```

How to get whole page length as opposed to hard code the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

document.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));
document.add(new Div().setHeight(5).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY));
document.add(new Paragraph("World"));

document.close();
```

To achieve the result as displayed on the image:

[image: result]

Comment: Could you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878140/itext-7-adding-border-for-the-page?

Comment: @user1578872 I posted an answer to that question 22 hours ago